# view "add product" - does not work

Tags: python, django

i created a model which contains name and price. I made a view that will help me with adding products on my site:

```
def new_expense(request):
    if request.method == "EXPENSE":
        form = ExpenseForm(request.EXPENSE)
        if form.is_valid():
            expense = form.save(commit=False)
            expense.save()
            return redirect('homebudget.views.expense_detail', pk=expense.pk)
    else:
        form = ExpenseForm()
    return render(request, 'homebudget/edit_expense.html', {'form': form})
```

Now i have something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RbQr.png
but when i click save there's nothing happening! What must i change in view?

forms.py:

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Expense
    fields = ('name', 'price',)
```

models.py:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    price = models.FloatField("price")
```

Answer (score 3):

`request.method` cannot be equal to `EXPENSE`, it may only be a [HTTP method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) name. In the same way, `request.EXPENSE`
 is not defined.
I don't know how the request is done but what you probably want to test is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ExpenseForm(request.POST)
```

Note:

```
expense = form.save(commit=False)
expense.save()
```

and

```
expense = form.save()
```

are equivalent.